# how can I consume rest api of one module from other module in same application using spring boot application without module dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working in multi Modules project. Currently I facing following issue:

- Module A
- Module B
- Module A has dependency on B
- Module A has following method
  @GetMapping(path = "/getworkspaces")

  ```
    public Map<String, Object> getWorkSpaces()) {
    Map<String, Object> workspaces = null;
    workspaces = this.dataSetService.getWorkSpaces();
    return workspaces;
  ```

  }
- Module B has following Method where I need to consume Module A mentioned endpoint

  public String consumeModuelAMethod()
  {

  ```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/getworkspaces"

    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseMap = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        if (HttpStatus.OK.equals(responseMap.getStatusCode())){
            return responseMap.getBody();
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (RestClientException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}}
  ```
- When I call "http://localhost:8080/getworkspaces" via RestTemplate from Module A.
- Its give me 404 (Not found)
- I am using secure api mechanism means SSO. So How to call api of one module in other module of same project without any dependency.
- Any help will be appreciate

Comment: could you access to this endpoint using CURL or Postman? if yes, you could try to re-verify your configuration for RestTemplate or enable logging to ensure that request is correct. Off Topic: cycle dependencies between modules (and even services) not good practice. try to avoid such situations. for example, split your code to modules in other way.

Comment: @ZhenyaM: I am accessing this via postman but I am also giving Bearer token id which I am getting from SSO.

Comment: If I m using sso for access token then how to get csrf token on server side to send with endpoint in header authorization

Comment: I have set the access token in header authorization and its work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the access token in header authorization and its work for me. – FaizUR Rahman